# Warning in eclipse for code formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Is there an option for Eclipse to issue a warning when code formatting does not match the current settings?

Also, how to can I find the best standards for formatting Java code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it'll show a warning.  However, Eclipse can automatically format your code for you.  You can select all using Ctrl+A, then hit Ctrl+Shift+F to auto-format your code.

Also, to see the Java conventions, you can go to Window, Preferences, Java, Code Style, Formatter.  Then, under Active Profile, select "Java Conventions," which I think is the same as "Eclipse (built-in)".  You can see a short example of what properly-formatted code should look like.

You can also see the document in its full gory detail at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) should suit your needs - you can configure the rules if required.

Answer (score 1):

You can also setup eclipse to automatically format your code when saving files:

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > **Save Actions**

Check **Perform the selected actions on save**, then check **Format source code** and choose to format *all lines*, or *edited lines*

Answer (score 0):

View: “Window” -> “Show View” -> “Problems”

Configuration: “Preferences” -> “Java” -> “Compiler” -> “Errors/Warnings”

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [HTML Tidy Plug-in](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/). Normally, Eclipse only displays compiler warnings and errors, and the compiler couldn't care less about style. However, you can set certain style warnings under  Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings.

As far as guidelines go, there's this [fairly comprehensive one](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/products/archive/whitepapers/java-style.pdf) published many years ago by Sun.

Answer (score 0):

http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Layout%20of%20the%20Recommendations

Comment: pro - a fairly complete and readble convention. con - mixes formatting and nameing conventions and includes java language spec (like location of package and import statement). And some recommendations are controversial (postfix for class members names)